# Handling events in Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

I have this simple HTML code:

```
<form id="filedrop"
    class="dropzone"
    action="{{ route('store.womenoffer.photo', ['id' => $id]) }}"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

And I want to add handling events. So I tried a few things:

```
$(function () {
    var myDropzone = $("#filedrop");
    myDropzone.on("success", function (file) {
        alert('Hello World');
    });
})
```

And this:

```
Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    accept: function(file, done) {
        accept: function(){
        alert('Hello World');
    },
    success: function(){
      alert('Hello World 1');
    }
};
```

All photos are uploaded correctly but events doesn't work. My backend code look like this:

```
$name = $this->uploadImg($request->file('file'), 'small');
if($name){
    Photo::create([
        'name'      => $name,
        'user_id'   => Auth::user()->id,
        'women_id'  => $id
    ]);
    return response()->json(['success' => $name]);
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** - [Here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/qLg95cu0/).

**Why didn't your code work?**

Your first try attaches events to jQuery objects, but not to Dropzone.

```
// This is a jQuery selector, you'll get your form as the result
var myDropzone = $("#filedrop");

// This attaches a handler for the "success" event - but there is no
// such event on a form.
myDropzone.on("success", function (file) {
```

Your second try is almost right, but does not attach handlers in the right way:

```
// This is the correct way to apply options ...
Dropzone.options.filedrop = {

// ... but this is not how to attach handlers
success: function(){
```

**OK, how to fix it then?**

[The Dropzone.js docs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage) describe that there are a few ways to instantiate Dropzone.  Simplest is by adding the class `dropzone` to your form, and that's it (BTW you don't even need to include `enctype` or `method` on your form).  This is what you have, so let's stick with this approach.

Next, [the configuration section of the docs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration) describes how to configure options in this case:

> ... if you just have HTML elements with the dropzone class, ... you have to store the configuration somewhere so Dropzone knows how to configure the dropzones when instantiating them.
>
> This is done with the Dropzone.options object.
>
> ```
> // "myAwesomeDropzone" is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID
> Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
> ```

So for your form that would be:

```
Dropzone.options.filedrop = { ... }
```

Finally, [the events section of the docs](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events) shows how to attache event handlers, and lists events and what parameters they receive.  `success` receives the file and the server response as parameters.

Putting it all together with your code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="filedrop"
    class="dropzone"
    action="{{ route('store.womenoffer.photo', ['id' => $id]) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
Dropzone.options.filedrop = {
    init: function() {
        this.on("success", function(file, response) { 
            alert("Hello World");
        });
    }
};
```

[Here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/qLg95cu0/).  It uploads a file to [JSFiddle's `/echo/json` endpoint](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/async-requests), which simulates a real POST to your backend.  The file is uploaded as normal, but nothing happens with it.

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't have any error so it's misleading

Comment: @Konfus2234 Looks like my selector was wrong - I got it working in JSFiddle, and I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Konfus2234 I found a way to show use real `success` handler, instead of just using `addedfile`.  This is exactly what you need, check it out! :-)